# Integration: How to evaluate $ \int^1_0 \frac {1}{1+x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can I calculate the integral  $$\int^1_0\frac{1}{1+x}\,dx\ \ ?$$

I am pretty good with derivatives but for some reason I never seem to get integrals, even though it's just the opposite of the derivative.

Comment: Try the substitution $u = x + 1$.

Comment: Think of the chain rule... the derivative of $f(g(x))$ is $f'(g(x))g'(x)$, when $f=\log$ that leads to $g'(x)/g(x)$ and then for $g(x)=1+x$ we reach $1/(1+x)$. Hence the primitive function is $C+ \log(1+x)$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: consider letting $u = 1+x\;\;du = dx$. Then,

$$\int^1_0 \;\dfrac{1}{1+x}dx \quad = \quad\int^2_1 \;\dfrac{1}{u}\;du$$

Comment: The antiderivative of $x+1$ is $\dfrac{1}{2}x^2 + x + C$ right?

Comment: Yes, you've just written the integral of $x + 1$ but in this case, $x+1$ is in the denominator. $\int (x+1) \;dx\neq \int \dfrac{1}{x+1}\,dx$

Comment: @Homework  yes that's right.

Comment: What is the integral of $\int \dfrac 1 u \;du$?

Comment: This will be a very hard unless you have learned about a certain special function whose derivative is 1/x

Comment: @amWhy ln(something), but I don't know what that something is

Comment: Exactly. $\ln|u| + C$. Now evaluate $\ln|u|\Big|_1^2$. I changed the bounds of integration, because when $x = 0, u = x+1 = 1,$ and when $x = 1, u = x+1 = 2$

Comment: @amWhy What will happen with the 1 in the denominator?

Comment: By substituting $u = x+1$ and changing the bounds of integration, we don't need to worry about $1$ because $u = x+1$

Comment: @amWhy I believe that is ln 2

Comment: YES!! $$\ln|u|\Big|_1^2 = \ln|x+1|\Big|_0^1 = \ln|2| - \ln|1| = \ln|2| - 0 = \ln|2| = \ln 2$$

Comment: @amWhy +1. I see you're taking my suggestion of giving hints out as it goes rather than typing up a full solution right away. :)

Comment: @Ahaan Thank you. If you follow my posts, over time, you'll see that I very often give out hints. (This was a Feb post). Depending on follow-up from the OP, I may clarify further in comments, or in an edited answer. But I often start out with just hints.